# Docker cannot create a machine - 'Error in driver during machine creation'

Tags: macos, docker, command-line-interface, virtualbox

No idea what the issue is with Docker - I am trying to get the daemon up/running but can't. Here is the error I get:

```
➜  ~  bash --login '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'
Creating Machine default...
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) OUT | Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) OUT | Creating SSH key...
(default) OUT | Starting VirtualBox VM...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 1
Starting machine default...
exit status 1
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n):
Regenerating TLS certificates
Detecting the provisioner...
Error getting SSH command: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : cat /etc/os-release
err     : exit status 255
output  :
Setting environment variables for machine default...


                    ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/
Error getting IP address: Host is not running
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
Error running connection boilerplate: default is not running. Please start it
in order to use the connection settings
```

I am running:

- Mac OSX 10.10.5
- Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
- VirtualBox version 5.0.10 r104061

I reinstalled the binaries via the [toolbox install tool](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_one/), but to no avail.

VirtualBox is giving a permissions error, so that may be the issue (I installed v4.3 but that didn't help):

```
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VMMR0.r0: The owner is not root
```

If this helps, here is the log output from Kitematic:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-machine -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default returned non zero exit code. Stderr: Docker Machine Version: 0.5.1 (7e8e38e) Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver-virtualbox
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Only 3 questions during the entirety of 2015 about Docker on Mac on this subdomain of stackexchange. Don't think I will find the audience I need there...

Comment: But this site is about programming, so it doesn't belong here...

Comment: I disagree. Docker is quickly becoming a tool used by programmers to build and ship code.

Comment: @Ben Rondeau - Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am going to update my OS and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Thanks for checking in though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to OSX 10.11 and problem went away. No idea why unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the virtual machine isn't getting created. Start with the same command Kitematic is running to get the full debug out and then add that to your question:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-machine -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve an issue similar.
The issue occurred when I installed docker toolbox a second time.

I uninstalled all Virtual box ethernet drivers virtual box itself and then docker toolbox.

I then recreated the boot2docker machine
docker-machine -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url=https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.9.0/boot2docker.iso  --virtualbox-memory 2048 default